# Resetting Values in ReactDOM Ref children (Best Practices?)

Tags: reactjs, stateless, react-dom

I've got a stateless component, called FlexibleInput.

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'

export default function FlexibleInput({
  id,
  label,
  defaultValue,
  type,
  onChange,
}){
  let fieldClass = `${id}-field`
  return (
    <fieldset className={fieldClass}>
      <label htmlFor={id}>{label}</label>
      <input
        key={id}
        id={id}
        type={type}
        defaultValue={defaultValue}
        onChange={onChange}
        />
    </fieldset>
  )
}

FlexibleInput.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  defaultValue: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  type: PropTypes.string.isRequired, // accepts "text", "password" atm.
  onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}
```

I use this FlexibleInput in a form called AddNote.

```
<form
  className="note-list__add-note"
  onSubmit={this.addNote}
  ref={`${this.props.type}-addNoteForm`}
  >
  <FlexibleInput
    id="note"
    label="Awaiting changes..."
    type="text"
    defaultValue=""
    onChange={(e) => this.setState({ content: e.target.value })}
    />
```

After submitting using the this.addNote function... I would like to be able to reset the FlexibleInput input value.

I've managed to do a ugly ass hack version...

```
this.refs[`${this.props.type}-addNoteForm`]
  .childNodes[0].childNodes[1].value = ''
```

Which manages to properly reset the value. This is prone to change because perhaps the structure of the FlexibleInput will change? I do not know, hopefully not.

But my main question is, is there a way that I could do a sort of

`this.refs[bla bla].find(#input)`

or so?

It is not very clear in the React/ReactDOM documentation which api is available for a `ref`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a [Controlled component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html) whereby the value of the input is set using using component state:

```
<form
  className="note-list__add-note"
  onSubmit={this.addNote}
  ref={`${this.props.type}-addNoteForm`}
  >
  <FlexibleInput
    id="note"
    label="Awaiting changes..."
    type="text"
    defaultValue=""
    value={this.state.content}
    onChange={(e) => this.setState({ content: e.target.value })}
  />
```

Then you just need to reset the content value within the `this.addNote` method:

```
addNote() {
  this.setState({ content: '' });
}
```

*N.B. Ensure you bind addNote correctly to ensure this.setState is correctly referenced.*

Comment: When I had tried this before, it would not allow me to edit the "value", but now (a few months later) that I am doing this, it is working as expected. Not sure if there was a bug on my end or what, but using a Controlled Component seems to be the way to go! Thanks :)

Comment: Do you remember what version of React you were using?  Either way glad I could help!

Comment: Unfortunately not. I believe it may have been my failure to properly bind the state and was still using the props so the 'live edit' or change into the value of the input was not showing.