# Change input field when state changes after user input

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to find a more React-type way of changing the input field when the state changes after a user input. This is my current setup, but I'm looking for a way to do this without signaling to the DOM in the `componentWillReceiveProps` method:

```
export default class Example extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {title: props.arr.question};
};

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  if(nextProps.arr.question !== this.state.title){
    let id = "question" + this.props.arr.key;
    document.getElementById(id).value = nextProps.arr.question;
    this.setState({title: nextProps.arr.question});
  }
}
  render(){

  return(<div>
<input type="text" id={"question" + this.props.arr.key} defaultValue={this.state.title} placeholder="Enter your title."/>
          </div>
        )
  }
}
```

What I assumed was that when the state changes, I will see the input change as well. In fact, that happens for any element except input fields, for some reason. So the only think that I found works is referencing the DOM in the `componentWillReceiveProps` method and change it like that.

Is there a better way to do this that I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **create a controlled component** by setting the value in your input directly with the value within your `state`.  Check out [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40795319/2902660), the application is similar.

So in your code be amended to:

```
export default class Example extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {title: props.arr.question};
  this.handleTitleChange = this.handleTitleChange.bind(this); 
  // ^--necessary to be able to call setState
};

handleTitleChange(e){
  this.setState({title: event.target.value});
  // this updates the state as the user types into the input
  // which also causes a re-render of this component
  // with the newly update state
}
render(){

  return(
     <div>
      <input type="text" 
        id={"question" + this.props.arr.key}
        defaultValue={this.state.title} 
        placeholder="Enter your title."
        onChange={this.handleTitleChange}  // to handle the change

        value={this.state.title}/>  // here is where you set 
                                    // the value to current state
     </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: So basically create a separate component just for the input?

Comment: No, you don't have to.  I've added the amendments you _could_ make to your code to get this working.

Comment: Only difference is that in my input for this particular question, I'm not directly entering the title in this specific input, but another one. But your solution worked. All I had to do was remove the `defaultValue` props, add an `onChange` prop and let the `onChange` handle the title change by setting the state, instead of calling DOM directly via vanilla JS.